# Simple confetti effect using CAShapeLayer and CoreAnimation on iphone?

Tags: ios, core-animation, cashapelayer

I am building a fairly simple game on my app. the app UI is based a lot core animation so does the game.
I am trying to achieve a simple confetti effect for the game using CAShapeLayer and core animation (in the style of the confetti in "cut the rope").

any help or direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well. for any one who looks.
it is now available for iOS 5 with CAParticleLayer & CAEmitterLayer.